# Reactjs 'includes' does not exist on type 'any'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to make a page that shows data, and lets the user filter it.
The part about showing data works, but when I add code to filter the dataset, it fails.

In the Render function, it fails on the line

```
let contents = App.renderUsersTable(this.state.users.filter(d => this.state.filterValue === '' || d.includes(this.state.filterValue)));
```

with the error: `TS2339 (TS) Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'never'.`

I've set my tsconfig.json to 'es2016', but that doesn't help.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2016",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "ES2016",      
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

App.ts:

```
import React from 'react';
import { TeamsThemeHelper } from './helpers';
import { Provider, ThemePrepared, Flex, Table, Avatar, Text} from '@fluentui/react-northstar';
import * as msTeams from '@microsoft/teams-js';

interface IAppProps { }

interface IAppState {
    theme: ThemePrepared;
    users: [];
    loading: boolean;
    filterValue: string;
}

export default class App extends React.Component<IAppProps, IAppState> {  
    constructor(props: IAppProps) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            theme: TeamsThemeHelper.getTheme('default'), 
            users: [],
            loading: true,
            filterValue: ""
        };

        msTeams.initialize();
        msTeams.registerOnThemeChangeHandler(this.updateTheme.bind(this));
        msTeams.getContext(context => { this.updateTheme(context.theme) });
    }

    onChangeHandler(e: { target: { value: any; }; }) {
        this.setState({
            filterValue: e.target.value,
        })
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.populateUserData();
    }

    static renderUsersTable(users: any[]) {
        return (
            <Table aria-label="table">
                <Table.Row header>
                    <Table.Cell content="Name"></Table.Cell>
                    <Table.Cell content="Job title"></Table.Cell>
                    <Table.Cell content="Department"></Table.Cell>
                    <Table.Cell content="Phone Number"></Table.Cell>
                </Table.Row>   
                
                {users.map(person =>
                    <Table.Row key={person.id}>
                        <Table.Cell content={<span><Avatar name={person.fullName} /><span className="Username">&nbsp;&nbsp;{person.fullName}</span></span>}></Table.Cell>
                        <Table.Cell content={person.jobTitle}></Table.Cell>
                        <Table.Cell content={person.department}></Table.Cell>
                        <Table.Cell content={<a href={"tel:" + person.phoneNumber1}><Text content={person.phoneNumber1} /></a>}></Table.Cell>
                    </Table.Row>  
                )}                
            </Table>            
        );
    }
  
    render() {     

        let contents = App.renderUsersTable(this.state.users.filter(d => this.state.filterValue === '' || d.includes(this.state.filterValue)));
        return (
            <Provider theme={this.state.theme}>        
                <Flex fill={true} column styles={{ padding: ".8rem 0 .8rem .5rem" }}>    
                    <input value={this.state.filterValue} type="text" onChange={this.onChangeHandler.bind(this)} />
                    {contents}
                </Flex>
            </Provider>
        )
    }

    private updateTheme(themeString: string | undefined): void {
        this.setState({
            theme: TeamsThemeHelper.getTheme(themeString)
        });
    }

    async populateUserData() {
        const response = await fetch('user');
        const data = await response.json();
        //console.log(data);
        this.setState({ users: data, loading: false });
    }
}
```

Comment: You have defined the type of `users` as an empty array.

Answer (score -1):

The `users` is empty and you don't insert any user to display, so it's an exception, since `d` does not exist.